# Problemas con DataSource en un servidor tomcat 8

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, tomcat, mariadb

Tengo un proyecto web en un servidor Tomcat (Windows 2008) con una base de datos MariaDB 10.0, para la conexión usamos el driver de mysql "mysql-connector-java-5.1.36-bin.jar".

He hecho una migración de TOMCAT de la version 6 a la 8. Aparentemente todo funcionaba bien, hacía el login correctamente, pero al rato (en unos 15 min) me he dado cuenta de que la aplicación no hacia el login, se queda esperando una respuesta del servido porque el login accede a la base de datos, mientras que si accedo a un pagina de la aplicación sin conexión a la base de datos me la resuelve correctamente.

Aunque esa aplicación no funcione otras que acceden a la base datos funcionan correctamente.

He estado investigando el código de mi servlet, haciendo debug he descubierto que cuando empieza a fallar el login es porque la aplicación se queda esperando a que el context le dé una conexión del pool.

Aqui esta mi codigo java:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
fuenteDatos = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/dataBase1");
```

Aqui teneis el codigo del context.xml:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/dataBase1" global="jdbc/dataBase1"
            auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            maxActive="100" 
            maxIdle="10" 
            maxWait="-1"
            removeAbandoned="true" 
            removeAbandonedTimeout="10"
            logAbandoned="false" 
            username="ares" 
            password="ares" 
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            LogSql="true"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dataBase1?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF8">  <property name="Pool.PingQuery" value="select 1"/>
<property name="Pool.PingEnabled" value="true"/>
<property name="Pool.PingConnectionsOlderThan" value="3600000"/> <!-- 1 hr -->
<property name="Pool.PingConnectionsNotUsedFor" value="10000"/> <!-- ping db 10 sec -->
```

Aquí adjunto el código de mi web.xml que hace referencia al pool de conexiones:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/dataBase1</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Y aquí algunas variables de conexión de MariaDB:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias por adelantado!

Comment: ¿Estás cerrando las conexiones en tu código Java? Ya sea que lo haces manualmente o que lo hace el framework que utilizas p.e. Spring Transaction.

Comment: Si, siempre creo la conexión de esta forma:

`Connection con = fuenteDatos.getConnection();`

Hago mis sentencias sql y despues lo cierro asi:

`con.close();
con = null;`

Comment: Puede que hayan operaciones que extrañamente no cierren la conexión. Sería bueno que obtengas un thread dump y memory dump de tu aplicación en ejecución para ver si hay procesos donde la conexión a base de datos sigue abierta y no en estado SLEEP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya he encontrado la solución al problema.
El problema estaba en el context.xml el atributo maxActive en tomcat 8 no existe. 
El substituto es maxTotal y al no encontrar el atributo me ponía el valor por defecto que es 8 y eso hacia que la aplicación se colapsara.